# How can I set a multiple text lines in Cytoscape.JS node content?

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

I have some cytoscape nodes with

```
  style: cytoscape.stylesheet()
    .selector('node')
      .css({
        'border-color': '#0266C8',
        'border-width' : '1px',
        'shape': 'data(faveShape)',
        'width': '80px',
        'font-family' : 'Consolas',
        'font-size' : '10px',
        'content': 'data(id)',
        'text-valign': 'center',
        'background-color': 'data(faveColor)',
        'color': 'data(textColor)'
      })
      ...
```

How can I have a content with two or more lines and 2 or more concatenated strings?

```
...
'content': 'data(id)' + '<br>' + data('name') + '<br>test123',
...
```

TIA

Answer (score 9):

In your stylesheet:

```
text-wrap: wrap;
label: 'My multiline\nlabel';
```

See http://js.cytoscape.org/#style/labels

Comment: Ok Don't forget to make `cursor:pointer` to work and maybe give us a baloon hint on mouse move.

Comment: What if I don't have carriage returns?